# Read available languages on an Android Device

Tags: android, android-activity, android-resources

How to read the available languages on an Android device programmatically? I know that the function Locale.getAvailableLocales() exist, however, can I completely trust that the language of each locale it returns is available on the device?

Comment: Please define "is available on the device". Do you mean "is something that the user can choose in the Settings app"?

Comment: Yes, something that the user can choose in the Settings.

Comment: You can trust `Locale.getAvailableLocales()`. However most locale-sensitive classes offer their own getAvailableLocales method, which should be preferred over this general purpose method.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 can you please explain what do you mean by " locale-sensitive classes". I am really new to this. Thanks.

Comment: There are some formatting related classes which has their own methods. See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getAvailableLocales%28%29